# How to get rid of the tabs referencing deleted SQL queries? (on startup)

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Content as per title. Will be updated if title won't be clear enough.

Restart of the tool didn't help. Closing the tabs doesn't help either.

I wonder if there is anything that can be done.

Comment: what do you mean by deleted query ? tabs of what, editor ? Why don't you just close them ? I don't understand what pour problem is.

Comment: I mean tabs. I can close them but when I open the tool again, the tabs are back.

Comment: can you explain more about your problem, it's not totally clear from what you have written right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have something to do with your IDE saving your workspace in the past and now being unable to overwrite it.

Check *Tools > Preferences > Environment* and see if (de)activating any of the following options and then restarting SQL Developer has any effect:

- **Save Everything On Exit**: toggle* it, close every tab and restart.
- **Automatically Reload Externally Modified Files**: deactivate it, close every tab and restart.
- **Check Externally Modified Files On Start**: deactivate it, close every tab and restart.
- **Local History > Enable Local History**: deactivate it, close every tab and restart.

<sub>* By toggle I mean: if it's off, turn it on; if it's on, turn it off.</sub>

The exact name of the settings may vary. You can have a look at [SQL Developer Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12152/intro.htm#CHDEDCJD) doc for further explanation of each option.